# Do these integral orthogonality relations imply pointwise relations?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lp-spaces, orthogonality, smooth-functions

Let $\mathbb{D}^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the closed $n$-dimensional unit ball. Let $f,h:\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be smooth.

> Suppose that for every smooth vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{D}^n$, $\langle h, df(V) \rangle_{L^2} =0$.
>
> Is it true that $\langle h(x),  df_x(v) \rangle_e=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{D}^n$ and every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

**I am asking whether these integral orthogonality relations* imply pointwise relations.**

I think that the answer is positive. My rough idea is to take "test fields" $V$ which are compactly supported on smaller and smaller neighbourhoods of $x$, but I am not sure if this approach actually works here.

*Just to clear, the assumption is
$$ \int_{\mathbb{D}^n} \langle h, df(V) \rangle_{e} =0 $$
where $\langle , \rangle_{e}$ is the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every smooth vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{D}^n$, $\int_{\mathbb{D}^n}{f’(x)(V(x))\cdot h(x)\,dx}=0$.

So, for every smooth vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{D}^n$, $\int_{\mathbb{D}^n}{f’(x)^*(h(x)) \cdot V(x)\,dx}=0$.

This implies that $f’(x)^*(h(x))=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{D}^n$.

In particular, for every smooth vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{D}^n$, $f’(x)(V(x)) \cdot h(x)=f’(x)^*(h(x)) \cdot V(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! I am embarrassed I did not think of this simple approach. Very elegant. (This is similar to integration by parts, where you "move a derivative" from side to side, just that here it is only an "algebraic manipulation").